# curl no URL specified error, even though URL is being specified

Tags: rest, http, curl

I'm attempting to execute the following CURL call via commandline:

`curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-u "m19389@dev.acp.co.com:qE2P/N7y1k.\(" \
-X GET -d "https://wefd.it.co.com:3905/events/com.co.mpm.dev.29160-wgdhfgd-v1/dsd/dsdfds-0-0-1-7c49768976-2g7kq"`

I've added quotes around the arguments and all, and I'm definitely inclusing the curl url, so I'm not sure what's going on here.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where is your data for the `-d` argument?

Comment: That was it.  I'm following ill-crafted documentation.  Thanks.